# How to findout which key was being used to login for an SSH session

Tags: ssh, bash

I would like to know which key was used when logging into an SSH session. I wan to correlate the key to a local database and send email to an address which corresponds to the key.

The first step is to find which key is the one being used.

Answer (score 12):

You will need to turn up logging.

On the client side, "ssh -v" will which private key was used.

On the server side, default log levels will only show that a public key was used (as opposed to password auth).  You will need to set the logging level in sshd_config to at least VERBOSE.

Comment: I would suggest `ssh -vvv`

Answer (score 6):

To do this you will have to raise the `LogLevel` of your sshd to `VERBOSE`.

```
logLevel VERBOSE
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart sshd. This will cause sshd to log the fingerprint of the key used to log in, to the configured log file (/var/log/secure, /var/log/auth etc). You will get a message similar to this

```
Dec  9 11:47:15 host sshd[32282]: Found matching RSA key: 54:d2:06:cf:85:ec:89:96:3c:a8:73:c7:a1:30:c2:8b
```

The `54:d2:06:cf:85:ec:89:96:3c:a8:73:c7:a1:30:c2:8b` is the fingerprint of the key used to log in.

You can obtain the fingerprint of a particular key by using the command

```
ssh-keygen -lf <keyfile>
```

where keyfile is the public key

```
sshkeygen -lf /tmp/test.key
2048 21:02:4b:82:83:62:49:d7:5f:e0:8f:cf:ec:a3:5f:38 /tmp/test.key (RSA)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to detect the *currently used ssh key* from *within the current ssh session*, then it seems there’s a better way since [OpenSSH 7.6](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.6):

Set `ExposeAuthInfo yes` in your server’s sshd_config. You should be able to limit this configuration to a specific user via `Match User geoaxis`.

Then, after restarting sshd and re-login, there should be an environment variable `SSH_USER_AUTH` that contains the path to a file with authentication information. In case of public key authentication this file contains the full public key prefixed with the string `publickey` .

This way you don’t need to manually add environment variables to your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 2):

The log idea from @user9517 is good and you can even have script monitoring the logs etc.

Additionally you can add `environment="SSH_KEY_ID=geoaxis"` before the actual key (see `sshd(8)`, `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT`) and then you can probably utilize that env var in /etc/profile or similar.

But also look at `sshd_config(5)`'s `AuthorizedKeysCommand`